# Total probabilities of being admitted to any university

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's provide an hypothetical situation in which a student applies to 10 different universities whose number of applicants, admissions and admission rate you can see in the table below.

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Name      | Applicants | Admitted | Admission rate |
------------------------------------------------------
| Columbia  |  329281    |  22885   |     6.95%      |
| Stanford  |  280915    |  19945   |     7.10%      |
| MIT       |  111963    |  10894   |     9.73%      |
| CalTech   |   17471    |   2231   |    12.77%      |
| Cornell   |  117590    |  21131   |    17.97%      |
| Berkeley  |  167324    |  36142   |    21.60%      |
| UCLA      |  159635    |  40675   |    25.48%      |
| Virginia  |   73030    |  24297   |    33.27%      |
| Rochester |   30261    |  10319   |    34.10%      |
| UCSD      |   80544    |  28593   |    35.50%      |
------------------------------------------------------
```

How can we estimate the total probabilities of being admitted in any of these 10 universities? We also have to take in account that some of the other applicants may have also applied to more than one university.

I'd be grateful if you could redirect me to any similar question or provide me any useful formula to solve this problem. Thanks for your interest.

Source: [USNews Education](http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally easier to solve by the completary situation, that is: What's the probability of NOT being accepted by any universtiy? Then the one you're looking for will be $1-x$. Now that's easier to calculate because you just have to use the product rule: probabilities of each of them multiplied, as it's only one way of not being accepted anywhere, which is all universities rejecting you, that is:

$$P(NO)=\Pi_i(1-p_i)$$
Being $p_i$ the admission rate/100. The result is 0.092, which is a 9.2%, so the probability of being admited in some university is 100-9.2=90.74%.

Comment: Thanks! It's been a really useful answer.

Comment: These aren't independent events, though, so your answer is going to be very off.

Comment: Why aren't they independent? If you apply to all of them, you will have those probabilities of each of them saying no or yes.

Comment: If you have gotten into MIT, you are a good enough student that you have a better than 35% chance of getting into UCSD or Rochester.

Comment: (So the events aren't independent, because there's some correlation, so you can't just multiply.)

Comment: So, what do you suggest?

Comment: @IOS_DEV I suggest you edit your question to make a note of this issue. I don't know how to proceed, but I also have no formal training in probability or statistics. Someone else probably will.